# Importing the numpy C-extensions failed on mac

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a problem with importing NumPy and pandas, already installed all the packages but trying to import them but getting the below error,
I also tried to uninstall and reinstall the packages again but didn't work.
here is the pip lists:
[image]
I also tried conda but couldn't solve the problem.
Btw: I am using Mac pro and atom.

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/**init**.py", line 23, in 
from . import multiarray
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.py", line 10, in 
from . import overrides
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/overrides.py", line 6, in 
from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import (
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-310-darwin.so, 0x0002): tried: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-310-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')), '/usr/lib/_multiarray_umath.cpython-310-darwin.so' (no such file)

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Desktop/test.py", line 2, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 144, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: 

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
installed.

We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:

    https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html

Please note and check the following:

  * The Python version is: Python3.10 from "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3"
  * The NumPy version is: "1.22.0"

and make sure that they are the versions you expect.
Please carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.

Original error was: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-310-darwin.so, 0x0002): tried: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-310-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')), '/usr/lib/_multiarray_umath.cpython-310-darwin.so' (no such file)
```